# Ionic Cordova build android fails at :processDebugGoogleServices due to "No matching client found for package name 'io.ionic.starter'"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using the Ionic framework to build mobile application.
As I'm going to finish the app, the build fails.
The output looks like the following.

```
Parsing json file: /Users/plum/Documents/Projects/bci-project/app/platforms/android/google-services.json
:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'io.ionic.starter'
```

And at the `google.services.json`, it's the following:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "123",
    "firebase_url": "https://cordova-plugin-firebase.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "cordova-plugin-firebase",
    "storage_bucket": "cordova-plugin-firebase.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:123:android:123",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.github.cordova_plugin_firebase"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "123.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "123"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 2
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

I tried to edit the `google.services.json` to change the package name to match with `config.xml` but when I build again, the `google.services.json` came back to the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the google-services.json to your project's root folder with the correct package name and then build.
Maybe you will need to remove and add the android platform again